# How can I show the containing directory in the window title?

Tags: vimrc, statusline

I'm trying to customize my window title, which uses the same [format](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27statusline%27) as the statusline. I know I can show the full path to the file with `%F` (or `%-0.20F` to restrict it to 20 characters). I'd prefer to show the file name separately (i.e. with `%t`). In this case, is there a way to show the full path to the containing directory instead?

If I don't set `titlestring` at all, vim's window title seems to default to

```
file.txt (/full/path/to/containing/directory) - VIM3
```

I thought I might pillage the code for this, but `set titlestring?` doesn't show anything.

Comment: @JairLópez That changes the title to `.` for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understood what you mean so feel free to correct me in the comment if I didn't understood.

If what you are trying to do is simply show the directory containing your file in your title bar you can use:

```
set titlestring=%{expand(\"%:p:h\")}
```

With this configuration when I'm on the help file `options.txt` my title bar looks like this:

[image]

Note that the example I gave you uses `expand` and the filename modifiers thus you can customize it the way you want with the help of [`:h filename-modifiers`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#filename%2Dmodifiers)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. But wow, that help page is confusing! Out of interest, what inspired you to look at this help page? I didn't see any reference to it in the `titlestring` or `statusline` pages.

Comment: @Sparhawk in [`:h 'titlestring'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27titlestring%27) an example mentions `set titlestring=%t%(\ %M%)%(\ (%{expand(\"%:~:.:h\")})%)%(\ %a%)` and I knew that `:~`, `:h`, etc are documented in `filename-modififers` :)